# Replace span text with title attribute onclick

Tags: jquery, replace, caption

I've got a script set up that changes a large image when a thumbnail is clicked. It also changes the title attribute successfully. I'd like it to take that title attribute and populate a span tag with the text. It works when the page loads, but when you click any of the thumbnails, the span disappears. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 function changeIt(imageName,titleCaption,objName){
var obj = document.getElementById(objName);
var imgTag = "<img src='"+imageName+"' border='0' title='"+titleCaption+"' />";
obj.innerHTML = imgTag;
var title = $("img").attr("title");
  $("span").text(title);
return;  
}
```

and the html

```
    <div id="gallerycontainer" style="height:530px;width:940px;">
<img src="http://foo.com/image/thumbnail.jpg" border="0" width="940" height="530" title="caption" />
<span id="gallerycaption">caption</span>
</div>


 <div class="workplease">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeIt('http://foo.com/image/large.jpg','caption','gallerycontainer');">
<img src="http://foo.com/image/thumbnail.jpg" border="0" width="190" height="106" alt="{title}" title="caption" />
</a>
</div>
```

The first div is the large image container, the second would be repeated as a series of thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'obj' contains the span. 
and you are using obj.innerHTML which is overwriting your span.  therefore, you have no span.

you can either update the img element that is already there, or you can find it and remove it, then append your new image tag instead of overwriting the entire gallerycontainer.

EDIT:

Add an id to each of the img elements. i used thumb and fullImage. then:

```
function changeIt(imageName,titleCaption,objName, link){
    var thumb = $(link).find('img');
    $('#fullImage').attr('src', imageName);
    var title = thumb.attr('title');
    $("#gallerycaption").text(title);
    return;  
}
```

Edit links to pass 'this'(ignore my image paths):

```
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeIt('../images/2.png','caption','gallerycontainer', this);">
        <img id="thumb" src="../images/2.png" border="0" width="190" height="106" alt="{title}" title="caption2" />
    </a>
```

Then you will have a reference to the exact thumb that was clicked.

Comment: Ok, I sort of understand what you mean, but I'm pretty new to javascript, do you think you could give me an example of how to re-write the script? Thanks so much!

Comment: getting closer :) that keeps the span tag in place, but now the text is always the same, how would I get it to update to the thumb that has been clicked? There are multiple thumbnails.

Comment: I have updated to code to pass 'this' which will reference the thumbnail image element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('span').innerHTML = title` instead.

Comment: hmmm, that still disappears after clicking any of the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `$('span').prop('title', 'Title Here!');`